# How can I pin-point the source of AWS S3 costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cost-explorer

I'm currently surprised by a pretty high daily AWS S3 cost of over 31 USD **per day** (I expected 9 USD - 12 USD per month):

- I'm using eu-central-1
- All buckets combined are less than 400 GB
- No replication

The best explanation I have is that the number of requests was way higher than expected. But I don't know how I can confirm this. **How can I narrow down the source of AWS S3 cost?**

Is it possible to see the costs by bucket?

Is it possible to see a breakdown by storage / requests / transfers / other features like replication?

Comment: If you look at your AWS bill details for the current month it will be broke out into storage, data transfer, etc.

Comment: KB article on [How do I find the cost of my Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-find-bucket-cost/)

Answer (score 0):

First pay attention to the factors on which AWS S3 charges - i.e. based on storage, how many requests s3 is getting, data transfer and retrieval.

Some of the ways for cutting and keep track on the cost -

- Delete the previous version of the buckets if you don't need that.
- Move the data to different s3 storage based on frequency of data retrieval.
- activate the cost allocation tags on your buckets so that you can review the cost on individual bucket.
- create an S3 Storage Lens dashboard for all the buckets in your account.